# WebCamTexture is not being rendered on a 3D plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to access HoloLens camera using WebCamTexture, it works fine on standalone app, I am passing the frames to DLL for image processing but when deployed on HoloLens the communication between the script and the DLL is perfect it also works fine. The problem is I am not able to render the frames on 3D plane.

I tried this code on standalone app as well as on hololens. If tried this code without calling the DLL it worked for me. But when passing the frames to DLL the the 3D plane is missing.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
    webcamTexture.Play();

    data = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];
}
```

Expected result: I want to display live video on 3D plane on HoloLens.

Comment: did you set the permissions? also did you call [Application.RequestUserAuthorization](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html) as it says in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.Play.html)?

Comment: I am using it on _HoloLens_ and **NOT** for iOS.

Comment: I don't know in the docs it says `Call Application.RequestUserAuthorization before creating a WebCamTexture.` .. it doesn't mention that it is only required on iOs.

Comment: Above code works fine when rendered on cube/plane. But when trying to pass the WebCamTexture data do the DLL along with rendering, the plane gets vanished but the app continues to work.

Comment: App works without this permission `Application.RequestUserAuthorization`

Comment: Than how are we supposed to help you if we have no clue how the DLL looks like or how exactly you are trying to pass the texture data to it?